# Improving speed of ParametricNDSolve for three-dimensional integration

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I'm trying to calculate a three-dimensional integral of a function depending on four parameters `a, b, c, d` via `ParametricNDSolve` after `NIntegrate` didn't really work out. My solution so far looks like this:

```
sol1 = ParametricNDSolve[ {Boole[
      Sqrt[(x - xj[a, c][[1]])^2 + y^2 + z^2] >= 1 \[And] 
       Sqrt[(x - xj[a, c][[2]])^2 + y^2 + z^2] >= a]*
     integrand[a, b, c, d, x, y, z] == f'[x], 
   f[-100] == 0}, f, {x, -100, 150}, {y, z, a, b, c, d}]
func1 = Evaluate[f /. sol1]
intx[y_, z_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := func1[y, z, a, b, c, d][150]

sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[{intx[y, z, a, b, c, d] == f'[y], 
   f[-10] == 0}, f, {y, -10, 10}, {z, a, b, c, d}]
func2 = Evaluate[f /. sol2]
intxy[z_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := func2[z, a, b, c, d][10]

sol3 = ParametricNDSolve[{intxy[z, a, b, c, d] == f'[z], 
   f[-10] == 0}, f, {z, -10, 10},  {a, b, c, d}]
func3 = Evaluate[f /. sol3]
intxyz[a_, b_, c_, d_] := func3[a, b, c, d][10]
```

This solution however works quite slowly. For reference: Evaluation of `intx` for a set of parameters happens almost instantly, evaluation of `intxy` takes 1-2 seconds and evaluation of `intxyz` takes about 4 minutes. As my goal is to plot `intxyz` for three fixed and one variable parameter `a, b, c, d`, this calculation takes far too long. Is there a way to improve the speed of `ParametricNDSolve` or would another method to calculate the integral be better suited for this problem?

EDIT:
`integrand` is given by

```
integrand[a_, b_, c_, d_, x_, y_, z_] := 
 2*Re[Conjugate[
     u0[a, b, c, d, x, y, z]].
     (u0[a, b, c, d, x, y, z][[1]]*
       Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0, 0][ut][x, y, z, a, c] + 
      u0[a, b, c, d, x, y, z][[2]]*
       Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0, 0][ut][x, y, z, a, c] + 
      u0[a, b, c, d, x, y, z][[3]]*
       Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0, 0][ut][x, y, z, a, c] 
       - {Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0, 0][ut][x, y, z, a, c][[3]], 
          Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0, 0][ut][x, y, z, a, c][[3]], 
          Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0, 0][ut][x, y, z, a, c][[3]]})]
```

where `u0` and `ut` are vector fields consisting of mainly polynomials and exponential functions of `r=Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]`.

Comment: Giving the definition of `integrand` would make it easier for people to try to help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Gaoloth! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Can you give definitions for `u0` and `ut`?